# how to getFile in grails

Tags: grails

How to get File in grails?
I tried this code but it's not success..

```
 def upload = {
        withForm{
            def f = request.getFile('filecsv')
            def orifilename = f.getOriginalFilename()
            def homeDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home")) 
            def homeurl = "Documents/Uploads/"
            File fileDest = new File(homeDir,homeurl+orifilename)
            f.transferTo(fileDest)  

            def card = Card
            def cif = Cif

            request.getFile(new File(fileDest)).InputStream.splitEachLine(',') {fields ->
            def loanaccount = new LoanAccount(
                totalLoanAmount: fields[0].trim(),
                outstandingAmount: fields[1].trim(),
                installmentAmount: fields[2].trim(),
                collectionDate: fields[3].trim(),
                dueDate: fields[4].trim(),
                interestRate: fields[5].trim(),
                card:card.findAllByCardNo(field[6]).trim(),
                cif :cif.findAllByFirstName(field[7]).trim()
                )
            if (loanaccount.hasErrors() || loanaccount.save(flush: true) == null)
            {
                log.error("Could not import domainObject  ${loanaccount.errors}")
            }
            }

            redirect(action:"list")

        }
            }
```

Why it error?

But it's error to get the file...

```
2014-02-04 15:38:50,648 [http-8080-11] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - Could not find matching constructor for: java.io.File(java.io.File)
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: java.io.File(java.io.File)
        at com.teravin.wallet.LoanAccountController$_closure12_closure16.doCall(com.teravin.wallet.LoanAccountController:322)
        at com.teravin.wallet.LoanAccountController$_closure12_closure16.doCall(com.teravin.wallet.LoanAccountController)
        at com.teravin.wallet.LoanAccountController$_closure12.doCall(com.teravin.wallet.LoanAccountController:308)
        at com.teravin.wallet.LoanAccountController$_closure12.doCall(com.teravin.wallet.LoanAccountController)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I am using `Grails 2.1.1`. I tried to find some documentation in google but still not able to solve my problem.

Comment: How about adding some more information about the error you get? Do you get an exception? If so please add the stacktrace and mark the line it is thrown.

Comment: yes, i already add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here

```
request.getFile(new File(fileDest)).InputStream.splitEachLine(',') {fields ->
```

You don't need `request.getFile` here as you've already handled the file upload and transferred it to a temporary file, just use

```
fileDest.splitEachLine(',', 'UTF-8') { fields ->
```

Note that you should probably use an explicit encoding for `splitEachLine` rather than relying on the platform default being correct. You could maybe examine the Content-Type sent by the browser to see if that specifies a charset, then fall back on a default of UTF-8 (or whatever) if it doesn't.

You also have a typo further down where you refer to `field[6]` and `field[7]` when the variable in question is actually called `fields` with an s.

Comment: i already change it...but it have an error..
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: field for class: com.teravin.wallet.LoanAccountController

 at com.teravin.wallet.LoanAccountController$_closure12_closure16_closure17.doCall(com.teravin.wallet.LoanAccountController:330)

 at com.teravin.wallet.LoanAccountController$_closure12_closure16.doCall(com.teravin.wallet.LoanAccountController:322)

 at com.teravin.wallet.LoanAccountController$_closure12_closure16.doCall(com.teravin.wallet.LoanAccountController)

 at com.teravin.wallet.LoanAccountController$_closure12.doCall(com.teravin

Comment: @akiong you've called the local variable "fields", not "field".

Comment: oh gotcha..thanks...
i got some eror..am i wrong for this line?card:card.findAllByCardNo(fields[6]).trim(),
    cif :cif.findAllByFirstName(fields[7]).trim()